# How to locate class name in the llvm bytecode, using call and alloca instructions?

Tags: c++, llvm

I have the following C++ code:

```
class Date {
public:  
  Date(int, int, int);
private:
  int year; int month; int day;
};

extern "C" int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   Date today(1,9,2014);
   //....
   return 0;
}

Date::Date(int d, int m, int y) { day = d; month = m; year =y; }
```

The corresponding bytecode is:

```
@_ZN4DateC1Eiii = alias void (%class.Date*, i32, i32, i32)* @_ZN4DateC2Eiii

define i32 @main(i32 %argc, i8** %argv) {
entry:
  %retval = alloca i32, align 4
  %argc.addr = alloca i32, align 4
  %argv.addr = alloca i8**, align 4
  %today = alloca %class.Date, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %retval
  store i32 %argc, i32* %argc.addr, align 4
  call void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata !{i32* %argc.addr}, metadata !922), !dbg !923
  store i8** %argv, i8*** %argv.addr, align 4
  call void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata !{i8*** %argv.addr}, metadata !924), !dbg !923
  call void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata !{%class.Date* %today}, metadata !925), !dbg !927
  call void @_ZN4DateC1Eiii(%class.Date* %today, i32 1, i32 9, i32 1999), !dbg !927
  //...
  ret i32 0, !dbg !930
}
  //...
define void @_ZN4DateC2Eiii(%class.Date* %this, i32 %d, i32 %m, i32 %y) unnamed_addr nounwind align 2 {
entry:
  //...
}
```

I'm doing a parse of this code and I need to extract the class name, in this statement:`% today = alloca% class.Date, align 4` 
Is there any way to see just returned: `class.Date`???

I also need to know how to get to `@ _ZN4DateC2Eiii` function, starting from the call:

```
call void @ _ZN4DateC1Eiii (class.Date% *% today, i32 1, i32 9, i32 1999)! dbg! 927.
```

Comment: Ok. What can you say about the second question??

Comment: I saw that you should ask it separately, in a new question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clang will utilize the class name for naming the LLVM type, as you can see in your example (it used `%class.Date` as the type name). However, the only reliable way to obtain the name of the type is to query the debug information. To do that:

1. Identify the `alloca` you care about.
2. Iterate the function until you find a call to `llvm.dbg.declare` where the first argument is a metadata node wrapping the value from (1).

   - You can use `isa<DbgDeclareInst>` for that.
3. Create a new `DIVariable` instance, passing the metadata node from (2) as the constructor argument.
4. You can retrieve the object's type - of `DIType` class - by calling `getType` on the object from (3). You can use `getName` on an object of type `DIType` to get the type name.